# Azure AppConfiguration with Spring Boot 2.5.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, spring-cloud, azure-app-configuration

## **Question**

How to integrate an `Azure AppConfiguration` with `SpringBoot 2.5.x` or higher?

---

**Info**

Im trying to use an `Azure AppConfiguration` resource with a `Spring Boot 2.5.4` project. Unfortunately I cant get it to read a setting from the AppConfiguration or even connect to it as far as I can tell.

The project is newly created with the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) where I only added

- Spring Boot Starter Web
- Spring Boot Starter Security
- Spring Boot Starter WebSocket

Afterwards I tried following the [Microsoft Quickstart documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-java-spring-app) with no success. The documentation mentions that its using `Spring 2.4.x` so I assume some changes broke it.

I also tried to identify the issue by looking through some [Azure Spring Boot Code Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples).

All the examples so far use the `bootstrap.properties` file which I learned during my search so far is deprecated. Moving the settings to the `application.yml` or enabling `use-legacy-processing: true` did not work either. Any ideas?

**pom.xml**

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  config:
    use-legacy-processing: true
  profiles:
    active: "develop"
  application:
    name: "MySampleService"
  cloud:
    azure:
      appconfiguration:
        stores:
          - connection-string: "SomeAzureAppConfigurationResourceConnectionString"
            label: ${spring.profiles.active}
#mysampleservice:
#  message: "this is a message from file"
```

**AppConfiguration Resource**
[image]
Im not entirely sure about the format for the setting name. I tried to build the format based on [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-spring-boot_3.6.0/sdk/appconfiguration/spring-cloud-starter-azure-appconfiguration-config/README.md).

The configuration classes should be fine since commenting in the `mysampleservice` causes the value of message beeing used.

Any hints are appreciated!

### Some more info to elaborate on the accepted answer

The documentation linked in the answer refers to two different packages. The one linked right at the start in the maven repository is `spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config` while the one used further down is `azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config`. The second one works with the `bootstrap.properties` file.

**Working `pom.xml` and `bootstrap.properties`:**

```
...
    <dependencies>
<!--        Dependency to load configuration from azure app configuration resource. Note that additional settings are required in bootstrap.properties
            Documentation of settings: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/appconfiguration/azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

```
# Use this to enable or disable the cloud config, disabling it results in application.yaml beeing used.
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.enabled=true

# Connection string to azure app configuration resource
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string= Endpoint=https://myofficeconfiguration.azconfig.io;Id=zUcT-l9-s0:PFYfW7WM0/Pz7WZOnH3v;Secret=JTB9myJqGekDAJ5m8Z1vjmkJZrPd88JbOEE3EqoqJYs=

# Configured filters for settings in the previous defined app configuration resource
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].selects[0].key-filter = /mysampleservice/
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].selects[0].label-filter = Sample
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].selects[1].key-filter = /notificationservice/
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].selects[1].label-filter = Sample2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap.yml/bootstrap.properties can still be used, they are no longer part of the base Spring packages.

Also, you want to use this doc for 2.0.0 and newer https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/appconfiguration/azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config.

Comment: Thanks, I took a closer look into this documentation the second time around and found my error with the packages!